# Change NSIndexPath when navigating back to UITableView

Tags: ios5, uitableview, nsindexpath

**SCENARIO** (iOS 5)
I currently have a UITableView.
It has 30 table rows
The user decides to click on row 5
A ViewController is pushed.
Within this ViewController the user has navigated forward 10 items.
When they navigate back to the UITableView they are at row 5 highlighted

**What I would like**
I want the UITableView to show table row 15 highlighted and in view, because they have moved 10 rows ahead within the ViewController.

**What I found**
I thought I would be able to modify the NSIndexPath row property to 15 when I navigate back. But documentaiton states it's **read-only**.

```
row  
An index number identifying a row in a section of a table view. (read-only)  

@property(readonly) NSInteger row  

Discussion
The section the row is in is identified by the value of section.
```

Any feedback on how I can get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to change the selection, use this `UITableView` method:

```
- (void)
selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
animated:(BOOL)animated
scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition;
```

You don't need to modify a particular index path to call that API, just create a new one; for example:

```
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
```